# async/await and promise in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to understand why the return type `string` in the following method is underlined red as error:

```
exportPageAsText(pageNumber: number): string {
        (async () => {
            const text = await this.pdfViewerService.getPageAsText(pageNumber);
            console.log(text);
            return text;
        })();
}
```

The error message reads: `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.` so I moved `return text;` out of the `async` scope and placed it after `})();` but that made the `text` variable unrecognizable.

Then I thought maybe it's because the method return type should be a `Promise` so I changed the signature to:

```
exportPageAsText(pageNumber: number): Promise<string>
```

But I get a new error saying that `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.`

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think that when you do that : `(async () => {` , you're creating a new function, so this is that function that should have a return type

Comment: you are not returning anything, juste executing the arrow async function . just add return before (async()=>...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `await`, so you need an async function. What you created is a self-invoking async function. But returning a value inside the self-invoking function does not return it for the base function.

What you are looking for is to make the base function async, and setting the return type to `Promise<string>`:

```
async exportPageAsText(pageNumber: number): Promise<string> {
  const text = await this.pdfViewerService.getPageAsText(pageNumber);
  console.log(text);
  return text;
}
```

Comment: How do I subsequently convert a `Promise<string>` to `string`? Somewhere else, I use `let text = this.pdfService.exportPageAsText(pageNumber);` and then use `.replace` on `text`, but of course I get an error that `.replace` is a `string` method, not `Promise<string>` method. I cannot make that one `async`; it has to be converted to a normal `string`, so to speak...

Comment: In this case you have to directly work with promises, for example something like `this.pdfService.exportPageAsText(pageNumber).then(text => { console.log(text); })`

Answer (score 2):

Your method wait a return before the end but event the promise declared by async () => {... is not returned

so two thing to change in your code

1. return the async()
2. change the type of return in the methode declaration by `Promise<string>`

In your case syntax it will look like

```
exportPageAsText(pageNumber: number): Promise<string> {
    return (async () => {
        const text = await this.pdfViewerService.getPageAsText(pageNumber);
        console.log(text);
        return text;
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would have done it. async/await.

```js
    const exportPageAsText = async (pageNumber: number): Promise<string> => {
        const text: string = await this.pdfViewerService.getPageAsText(pageNumber);
        console.log(text);
        return text;
    }
```